# generate all possible column combinations and create one matrix for each of them in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this one:

```
myarray=cov(matrix(rexp(200),50,10))
```

I would like to generate all possible combinations of columns and compute the correlation matrix for each combination, if possible, using column numbers instead of names. In a second step I would like to compute the determinant of each matrix so maybe there is an efficient way to do it.

Comment: But, none of the column combinations will result in a square matrix.. ?

Comment: @Arun well in fact I want to calculate the correlation matrix and then calculate its determinant

Comment: what does `det(cor(myarray))`?

Comment: @Seth this is the correlation matrix for the whole matrix but I would like to get all possible combinations of matrices, calculate its correlation matrix, and then its determinant or its eigenvalues, etc.

Comment: all possible combinations means that there will be pairwise and more than two, in my example there are 10 columns.

Comment: So you want to compute a correlation matrix for all of the 1024 = 2^10 columnwise subsets of myarray? all of those matrices will be elements from cor(myarray).

Comment: @Seth Yes this is what I try, but the correlation matrix is just an example as I said before I sould like to compute more things from each column's combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
list.of.matrices <- apply(expand.grid(rep(list(c(FALSE, TRUE)), ncol(myarray))),
                          1, function(j)myarray[, j, drop = FALSE])

length(list.of.matrices)
# [1] 1024
```

Then do something like:

```
result <- sapply(list.of.matrices, function_of_your_choice)
```

but note that `det` can only be applied to square matrices... Please clarify.

Comment: is there any way to mix do.call with sapply so that I can construct the squared matrix before I use sapply to calculate the determinant?